# Or-Tools - Job shop minimize restriction by each day

Tags: or-tools

I have a algorithm based on the JobShop.
the objective is to minimize the number of parts spent each day by the tasks allocated to the day.
after i get the sum by day, i then get the difference from each day to the average and minimize it.
It works.

As for the sum of the day, maybe not the best approach as it is still very slow to give out solution.
where can i optimize it?

Regards

```
List<IntVar> partsPerDay = new List<IntVar>();
List<List<IntVar>> parts_day = new List<List<IntVar>>();
IntVar[] day_constant = new IntVar[Options.NumDias_A_Planear];
IntVar[,,] parts_per_day_and_task = new IntVar[allJobs.Count, allJobs[0].Count, Options.Num_Days_To_Schedulle];


for (int k = 0; k < Options.NumDias_A_Planear; k++)
    day_constant[k] = model.NewIntVar(k, k, $"day_constant_{k}");

List<IntVar> parts_per_day = new List<IntVar>();

//...

for (int jobIx = 0; jobIx < allJobs.Count; ++jobIx)
{
    List<Task> job_tasks = allJobs[jobIx];
    for (int taskIx = 0; taskIx < job_tasks.Count; taskIx++)
    {

        //suffix
        string suffix = $"_{jobIx}_{taskIx}";
        //
        Task task = job_tasks[taskIx];

        //...

        //store a variable 'is_on_day2' with the day a task is going to start
        int slots_per_day = 96;
        IntVar aux = model.NewConstant(slots_per_day);
        IntVar day2 = model.NewIntVar(0, int.MaxValue, $"task_{suffix}_is_on_day2");
        model.AddDivisionEquality(day2, task.Vars.start, aux);//day2 = day / aux
        task.Vars.is_on_day2 = day2;
    }
}

for (int jobIx = 0; jobIx < allJobs.Count; ++jobIx)
{
    List<Task> job_tasks = allJobs[jobIx];
    for (int taskIx = 0; taskIx < job_tasks.Count; ++taskIx)
    {
        var task_id = Tuple.Create(jobIx, taskIx);
        Task task = allTasks[task_id];

        if (task.Duration == 0)
            continue;

        //# of parts of current task
        IntVar task_num_parts = model.NewConstant(task.Num_Parts);


        for (int i = 0; i < Options.Num_Days_To_Schedulle; i++)
        {
            IntVar i_var = model.NewConstant(i);

            //task is on day 'i'
            BoolVar b1 = model.NewBoolVar($"task_{task_id}_is_on_{i}");
            model.Add(day_constant[i] == task.Vars.task_day).OnlyEnforceIf(b1);
            model.Add(day_constant[i] != task.Vars.task_day).OnlyEnforceIf(b1.Not());

            //task[jobIx, taskIx, i]
            model.Add(parts_per_day_and_task[jobIx, taskIx, i] == task_num_parts).OnlyEnforceIf(b1); 
            model.Add(parts_per_day_and_task[jobIx, taskIx, i] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(b1.Not());



            //
            parts_day[i].Add(parts_per_day_and_task[jobIx, taskIx, i]);

        }
    }
}


//part sum
for (int i = 0; i < Options.NumDias_A_Planear; i++)
{
    model.Add(partsPerDay[i] == LinearExpr.Sum(parts_day[i]));
}

model.Add(total_parts == LinearExpr.Sum(partsPerDay));


//...
```

Comment: please add cross link when you multi post, otherwise it adds noise for us, maintainers...
ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/discussions/3761